# Error recovery implementation in a micro service architecture

Tags: error-prevention

We have a system that people can use to create new "Folders", a folder will have metadata about it (creation date, permissions, owner, etc.). The folder name is the unique key because there are automatic jobs that links to them by name.

Those jobs are created when the user defines a new folder. We are very explicit about how the creation of a folder instantly create a workflow in other systems and that the name is super important and ask the users to confirm their create action.

Every now and then, a user will not properly read, or will want to try something then message the support group to be able to rename or delete a folder, which can't be done in our system. A folder could be archived, but not deleted.

I have a manual process that can be done to delete or rename a folder, but it is very tedious and could impact live workflow. I was wondering if anyone knows a good recovery mechanism for an architecture like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing an input mask as the name of the folder with very clear instructions next to it about how to name the folder. Do not allow the user to confirm the name until all conditions in the input mask have been met.